# Exponential distribution problem 2

Tags: probability, exponential-distribution

A car is new at the beginning of a calendar year. The time, in years, before the car
experiences its first failure is exponentially distributed with mean 2.
Calculate the probability that the car experiences its first failure in the last quarter of
some calendar year.

Step 1:Let x=time in years before car experience first failure.

$$\sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} P(0.75+n<x<1+n)$$ n=some year

Step 2: Since x exponential the cumulative function is $F(x)=1-$e^-(x/$\theta$)

Step 3. $F(1)-F(0.75)=0.081$

the correct answer is 0.205,can someone help me get on the right track to solve this problem.

Comment: Where did you consider P(1.75<x<2)? And P(2.75<x<3)? And...

Comment: In your displayed equation, there an $n$ on the summation sign, but none in the expression for the term(s) to be summed.

Comment: Sorry but why don't you follow up on your revised step 1? Can't you express the sum of the series in terms of the CDF recalled in step 2?

Answer (score 1):

Your series summation results in

$$\frac{e^{-0.75/\theta}-e^{-1/\theta}}{1-e^{-1/\theta}}$$

or

$$\frac{F(1)-F(0,75)}{F(1)} = 0.205 \, .$$